# Where's a good starting point for programming?

Tags: objective-c

I recently started looking at programming and have been quite interested in it. The only bad thing is that I don't know how code works, where I can write it, or what languages to take into consideration.

I want to learn how to make applications for the iOS operating system, and i heard Objective C is the language for that. Is Objective C something you would recommend to a beginner?

I just wish I could grasp the concept of programming a little better and get a better understanding because, as of right now, it seems extremely complicated.

Comment: There are free iOS classes from Stanford available on iTunes U. I used them and they were hugely helpful.

Comment: there is nothing like a language for beginner. To learn how to program most often is a painful and frustrating thing. So my advice: don't code the typical code samples but think of something you would like to use. related to your activities what so ever. divide your project in small tasks. and start coding. said said: you won't find much of ObjC documentation addressed to beginners as it is usually not something you get in touch with when you start. But I think, you can try as ObjC has a rather small language core, not many keywords.

Comment: and I find apples docs about object orientated programming quite good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a beginning programmer, I would advise that you'd be better served learning how computers and programs work as a general concept, which will orient your thinking as to how programs are made.

I've heard lots of good things about the Haskell language in this regard, and I would recommend you start here: http://tryhaskell.org

Once you have a good concept of how programs work, and what kind of thinking and organisation is required, then you can move on to languages like C/Objective-C, which would be very frustrating to start on.

Comment: Remember to up vote any helpful answers or comments, and don't forget to accept an answer at some point.  (Usually the one you found most helpful)